# What does this old mark mean?

Tags: punctuation

> Now banish the **pathetic。** from public discourses, and you reduce the speakers merely to modern eloquence; that is, to good sense, delivered in proper expression.
>   Hume, *On Eloquence*

There are lots of this sort of old marks in this article by David Hume. I am totally at a loss what function this special mark has.

Answer (score 7):

It is an "[Ideographic Full Stop](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3002/index.htm)"<sup>1</sup>

> In some Asian languages, notably Chinese and Japanese, a small circle is used instead of a solid dot: "。"
>   <sub>[[Source]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_stop#Full_stops_in_other_scripts)</sub>

---

@KaiserOctavius encouraged me to search a bit more and although most of the links I found searching that quote didn't have the "。", [one result](http://www.econlib.org/library/LFBooks/Hume/hmMPL51.html#PATHETIC) did have the "[degree sign](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b0/index.htm)" °.

On that page, it appears the author was just using these marks as links to the glossary, indeed, clicking the symbol took me to a glossary entry for pathetic.

[image]

---

<sub>1. I didn't get this as a linguist, I got this is a programmer! I found a "[Character to ASCII converter](http://www.branah.com/ascii-converter)" and used that to find out the hexadecimal ID of the character, then I used [another online tool](http://www.fileformat.info/search/google.htm?q=3002) to find out the character's name, then googled that name. Rinse and repeat for other unknown characters</sub>

Comment: Clearly that is not its function here.

Comment: That doesn't mean that's not what the character is. The mark itself may be error. It's worth noting that when I google the quote, most results don't have that mark and those that do are links to this question.

Comment: I reversed my downvote after your latest edit. My problem with your original answer was that it seemed irrelevant in this context.

Comment: Rightly so, your downvote was justified and had the beneficial effect of me looking for another, better answer.

Comment: It is fairly common for words in a text to be highlighted as being defined in a glossary with the degree sign (I am currently setting a book that does the exact same thing). I admit I haven’t seen the ideographic full stop used in this manner before, but it’s not much of a stretch.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet That's almost certainly what's involved here. The sign does not appear in Hume's original; OP is probably using a modern school-text which uses the sign to distinguish editorial glosses from Hume's own footnotes. The use of the ideographic full stop is presumably OP's own interpretation of a degree sign in the original.

Comment: I just edited the question for formatting and realised that the parentheses the asker had used were ideographic parentheses, too, rather than ‘regular’ ones; this adds weight to Stoney’s conclusion and leads me to believe the asker is in fact Chinese, where the ideographic full stop would be an obvious (and easily typable) substitution for the degree sign.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I think I have seen the symbol "°" used for links to a glossary or some such; now I wonder why one would use this symbol and not something else, such as an asterisk or a dagger, or underline the word, or use small capitals. Any idea? It seems to be a rather recent invention.

Comment: Depending on the text, the number of such marked words, the type used to set the text, etc., any of those alternatives might prove more distracting than the degree sign. In the text I am currently setting, bold and italic text already have different meanings, asterisks are quite big and ungainly in the type used (PMN Caecilia), and I need to distinguish two different kinds of glossary; therefore, I mark them with a raised full stop (which I can't type on my phone, unfortunately) and the degree sign, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

If I might clarify James Webster's point, I think the lesson here is that the questioner's source (directly or indirectly) is a modern electronic version which included hyperlinks to editorial notes, and he or she is mistakenly interpreting the hyperlinks as 'old marks' in the original.

Comment: Yes, you are totally right. I mistook it as an old mark.